# Add a simple data entry form to populate a background list or access database

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, form, list-form

I am looking for assistance as I am new to SharePoint.

I need to build a simple form with 4 columns (*name, date, item description, quantity*) along with a submit button. Form will be used for daily issuance of items and I am open to the simplest way to store the data(list, access database, spreadsheet).

I have created a form with input fields and button button but I don't know how to connect it with data source.

Is there a tutorial available? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why don't you use SharePoint list for your data entry? You can add the list to the existing home page as a web-part. SharePoint list has default form that you can use for data entry without any customization

Answer (score 0):

The main step is to enable the submit data connection, and then the Data Connection Wizard automatically adds a Submit button to the forms toolbar, which lets you submit edited values for the selected order to the database tables.

Here are some articles for your reference:

[Submit form data to a Microsoft Access database.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/submit-form-data-to-a-microsoft-access-database-e1ce3695-6204-4e89-8f89-4e26cc5f3b25)

[Connecting Forms to Databases.](https://flylib.com/books/en/1.372.1/connecting_forms_to_databases.html#fastmenu_10)